# Run dotnet process in separate windows on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu

The below code works fine on Windows and I'm able to run this code and it opens a window for each different process but it runs on Linux without any errors but doesn't open separate windows for each process. How do I get my programs to run in separate windows on Linux/Ubuntu?

```
var process = new ProcessStartInfo
{
     UseShellExecute = true,
     WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
     FileName = "dotnet",
     Arguments = Path.Join(path, file)
};
Process.Start(process);
```

Comment: Can we assume you mean that this is a console application and that you mean different terminal windows?

Comment: @Llama Yes correct. I'm sorry if I wasn't explaining my issue clearly